SwiftData: adding a UUID to an existing model always creates the same id
I have a problem updating a SwiftData model by adding a property.
Specifically, I have the following model and I am trying to update it by adding an id. The problem is that, if I do this, all records already stored in the app get updated with the same UUID. Obviously I would like to have a different id for every instance. Am I missing something? Should I do something differently?
Reproducible example
First, I create the container using .modelContainer(for: Word.self) on WindowGroup in the App struct, as usual.
Word model: V1
@Model
class Word {
    private(set) var term: String = ""
    
    init (term: String) {
        self.term = term
    }
}

ContentView: V1
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query private var words: [Word]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(words) { word in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(word.term)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("SwiftData")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Insert") {
                    modelContext.insert(Word(term: "Swift"))
                    modelContext.insert(Word(term: "Apple"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

After running this version and adding a few instances of Word, we can try to add a wordId property.
Word model: V2
wordId property added.
@Model
class Word {
    var wordId: UUID = UUID()
    private(set) var term: String = ""
    
    init (wordId: UUID, term: String) {
        self.wordId = wordId
        self.term = term
    }
}

ContentView: V2
Let's reflect the changes.
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query private var words: [Word]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(words) { word in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(word.wordId.uuidString)
                    Text(word.term)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("SwiftData")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Insert") {
                    modelContext.insert(Word(wordId: UUID(), term: "Swift"))
                    modelContext.insert(Word(wordId: UUID(), term: "Apple"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The error I get
Upon running the updated version of the app, it is clear that every instance of Word underwent a lightweight migration and the new property was added... but the UUID is the same for every Word, rendering it useless.

You really should not add a property called id in your @Model. There is already a built-in unique id of type PersistentIdentifier, which is also Codable. If you really want your own UUID, call the property something else.

Can you show a [mre]? How did you do the migration?

This can be reproduced by performing a lightweight migration. Comment out the id property and run the code and create some Word objects, quit the app and uncomment the property and run it again.

I updated the question with a reproducible example.

Use like this :
struct Word {
    var wordId: String = UUID().uuidString
    private(set) var term: String = ""
    
    init (term: String) {
        self.term = term
    }
}

